# android animation for buttons to move from right to left

Tags: android, android-animation, objectanimator

I have totally 7 buttons at bottom of screen as like menus. In that, 4 buttons is visible when i click that 4th button first 3 buttons are move away from right to left and next 3 buttons are come into that place and vice versa. What type of animation should i use for this os is it possible to use [`TranslateAnimation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) or how to use [`ObjectAnimator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html)

Give any suggestions.

Comment: you need to give more details of what you want. TranslateAnimation will be sufficient for just moving buttons though.

Comment: There are three types of animators you can use property animators, view animators and drawable animators . It depends on what you are looking to do and what API level you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a view animation (like translate animation), is not going to move the actual button mechanism, just where it is visually drawn on the screen. Ie. when your buttons move, the area to click them will still be in the original position. If you want your actual object to move then a property animation (value animator, object animator, or view property animator) is the best choice.

You can read more about property animation and how to use them here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html